# Uninstall a Program from multiple remote computers and generate a report

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Question 1: I have a script below that will uninstall the program on local host but in the output I just need the hostname and uninstall status

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name = 'Test'"

$app.Uninstall()
```

Question 2:  I have a script below  which is running on multiple remote machines, it is doing the thing but the out-file results are false sometimes . I need an output to a file with columns hostname and Uninstallation status

```
$computers = (Get-Content 'C:\Test\testmchines.txt')

foreach ( $computer in $computers ) {

    $Test = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name Like '%Test%'" -ComputerName $computer

    if ($Test) {
        "Found {0} on {1}" -f $Test.Name, $computer

        $result = $Test.Uninstall()
        if ($result -eq 0) {
            "Uninstall successful on {0}" -f $computer | out-file 'C:\Test\uninstall.txt' -Append
        }
        else {
            "Uninstall failed on {0}" -f $computer | out-file 'C:\Test\uninstall.txt' -Append
        }
    }
    else {
        "Test is not found on {0}" -f $computer | out-file 'C:\Test\uninstall.txt' -Append
    } }
```

Please suggest correction in the above script to get the required output.

Required Output: A report/file with Hostname and Uninstall Status, Test application not found columns

Comment: You should not query `Win32_Product` and pipe cmdlets to `Get-Member` to explore what other information is available to select..etc `Get-Volume -DriveLetter c | GM`

Answer (score 0):

For report purposes you could use `CSV` formatted file. Make an object containing required information and using `Export-Csv` cmdlet export data to a file. I have changed your script a little to show you the object creating and setting its properties according to process conditions.

I hope you have got the point.

```
$computers = @(Get-Content 'C:\Test\testmchines.txt')

foreach ($computer in $computers){
    $Obj = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{ComputerName=$computer;TestExists=$false;Uninstalled=$false}

    $Test = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name Like '%Test%'" -ComputerName $computer

    if ($Test){
        $Obj.TestExists = $true
        $result = $Test.Uninstall()
        if ($result -eq 0) {
            $Obj.Uninstalled = $true
        }
    }
    $Obj | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Test\uninstall.txt' -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: In the above script I just replaced the "Test" Application with the Application needed ex: "Google Chrome" and running on 3 remote machines. Script didn't error out but neither it created a output file with results, neither it uninstalled the application. Any further suggestions are appreciated